# Referencing json list value created in Rundeck Data Workflow step

Tags: rundeck

Rundeck job: When I create data in data workflow step as json list

```
{
"repo": ["repo1","repo2","repo3"],
"myrepo": "repo4"
}
```

how can I access the elements in the list from inline script in next step?

```
@stub.repo[1]@
```

doesn't work

```
@stub.myrepo@
```

works fine

[Data Workflow step executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF6mE.png)

**Script:**

```
echo "value: @stub.repo[1]]@"
echo "value2: @stub.myrepo@"
```

**Result:**

```
value: 
value2: repo4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to catch that array is to use the [jq-JSON mapper log filter plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jq-json-logfilter) in any step like the command step or script step ([here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jq-json-logfilter/releases) are the releases, [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installation) is how to install the plugin, and [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/#log-filters) how Log filters works).

Using this plugin you can use the array positions directly, e.g: `${data.data.0}`, `${data.data.1}`, etc.

Job definition example with your JSON output for [testing](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions).

```yaml
- defaultTab: summary
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  group: JSON
  id: f0d2843f-8de3-4984-a9ae-2fd7ab3963ae
  loglevel: INFO
  name: test-json-array
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            filter: .[]
            logData: 'true'
            prefix: data
          type: json-mapper
      script: |-
        cat <<-END
        {
        "repo": ["repo1","repo2","repo3"],
        "myrepo": "repo4"
        }
        END
    - exec: echo ${data.data.0}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: f0d2843f-8de3-4984-a9ae-2fd7ab3963ae
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxGQg.jpg).

More info about the plugin [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/json-jq.html#usage).

Comment: Thanks, works fine, just needed to add quiet output log filter with data workflow step.